# Broadcast from Angular to a jQuery Listener

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Trying to get AngularJS to broadcast a custom event that jQuery is listening for.

In the jQuery I have something similar to this:

```
$( document ).on( "myCustomEvent", function( event, data ) {
    $( this ).text( data.myName + ", hi there!" );
});
```

In the AngularJS I have something like this:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('myCustomEvent', data);
```

Shouldn't jQuery be able to listen for the broadcast that AngularJS is broadcasting or is tied to AngularJs only with this:

```
$scope.$on.('myCustomEvent', function(event,data) {
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Demo http://plnkr.co/edit/WFERKW?p=preview

In general, event that is triggered on a DOM element will bubbling up the DOM tree to all parents of target element. So you can inject `$element` service in your controller and trigger event on it.

```
// Document as a parent of `$element` will receive this event
$(document).on('myCustomEvent', function(event, data) {
  console.log(data);
});


// In controller
$element.trigger('myCustomEvent', {myName: 'Steve Jobs'});
```

#### Attention

1. `$element` service cannot be injected every where. In a controller, you can use `$element`, in a directive, you should use `element` argument from link function.
2. You could also use `$document` service to trigger `event` on.
3. Besure to include jQuery before Angular library, so jquery method will be automatically included in `$element` and `$document` services.

Comment: Hi Daiwei, I changed it to document as I have the whole document listening for it but trigger did not work in my case.  If someone cannot figure out then I will create a jsfiddle to give better information.

Comment: @Orison Just updated the answer to reflect your request.

Comment: Awesome I should have posted here sooner to save myself the 15 hours trying to get it to work. The plunker example was the kicker as my controller did not have the $element command injected but once it did the code ran without a hitch.  Have a blessed day, Orison

Answer (score 0):

I've got to be a nay-sayer; don't do this.  What you are doing, modifying the DOM based on an event, is literally what angular was built for.  Bringing jQuery into the picture is unnecessary, and only adds complication.  Look into `ng-bind` and `ng-model` to see how to update the DOM in response to your data changing.

Comment: I do not disagree with your logic as I think it should be refactored to use AngularJS throughout as it will make the software better but when working with existing software you have to balance many other factors and make concessions in order to keep moving forward and this one of those situations.