# Access angular scope from outside function on load

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I have a bit of a problem with an Angular application. Basically I want to manipulate the scope outside of the application itself. If I type in the console:

`$scope = angular.element($('.lead-system')).scope()`

I can use `$scope` with `$apply` and it all works fine. However, when I use this in a rails coffeescript file:

```
angular.element(document).ready ->
  console.log angular.element($('.lead-system')).scope()
```

It logs `undefined` and of course I can't use `$apply` with that.

What's up with that? I'm loading the JS files in this order:

`app.js` <-- Main angular app initializer

`pending.js.coffee` <-- The file listed above

`lead_controller.js` <-- The controller of the scope I'm trying to access

Comment: angular ready did not mean, that the first digest cycle is ready or your controller is instantiated. $scope is available if the controller or directive is instantiated. btw: this ist really not the way how you should use angular: angular.element($('.lead-system')).scope(). Why is this necessary?

Comment: That's what I'm looking for: The ready event to use when that scope will become available. As for why: Because another part of the page needs to add products to a scope variable when clicked. It's a self contained application but various other parts of the page need to load it with initial data when you click a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in the $timeout, just to check if it will work then. That should tell you if this can be fixed by different timing or give you ideas for further exploration.

My recommendation though would be to fire an event (emit/broadcast or even arbitrary external thing in your case) in controller and in reponse to that event manipulate the scope. You could even pass the scope as parameter for convenience.

Comment: You read my mind, I just wrapped it in a timeout for 500ms and it works perfectly :) However that's not the best way to do it so I'll look at how to fire an event in the controller

Comment: How would I emit an event from the controller that I can listen for in jQuery? I've tried `$(document).trigger('leadControllerLoaded')` but `$(document).on('leadControllerLoadded')` doesn't work

Comment: i do not use jqyery so can not help here. Try the simple thing first. Set a function on window that will do your stuff to passed in object. Then just call that from angular controller using $window. When that simplistic thing works you can move on to figure out any architectural twist that is appriopiate with that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21125332/broadcast-from-angular-to-a-jquery-listener/21128843#21128843   Try this. Seems like exactly your issue.

Comment: Brilliant... Just what I needed :)