# Listening events between Angular and Non Angular Apps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, dom, eventemitter

I have angular and non-angular apps on same page. I emit an event in angular app and want to listen to it in a non-angular app. Can someone please give some suggestions on how can I achieve this?

I have successfully implemented an event emitter that was able to trigger and listen to events between parent and child components of angular but it  needs inputs for listening to the emitter event on non-angular app.

Comment: Try using rxjs fromEvent

Comment: What about custom window events https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344625/create-javascript-custom-event ?

Comment: @adam kosmala .. Yep I used window events and it works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer it has some nice suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28773900/how-do-i-communicate-between-an-angular-app-and-non-angular-app-on-the-same-page/28805946)

I would suggest this approach using javascript

```
var ngScope = angular.element('[ng-controller]').scope();
```

Checkout the answer by @Moshe Shaham, it's a great answer

Comment: Let me know if this works for you